# Wifi drops intermittently on Macbook Air

Tags: macos, wifi

I have read the other articles with a similar issue but they don't have the exact same issue as I do, hence this post. The Wi-Fi on my macbook air keeps dropping intermittently but works perfectly fine on my Windows laptop and Android phones at the same time. I have been having this issue for over 4 months now.

Note: The Wi-Fi bars at the top right corner remain the same but the internet stops working.

Here are the details of my Macbook and router:

- 2011 Macbook Air with OS X El Capitan v 10.11.6
- Router: D-Link model DIR 600M

I have tried the below options but nothing worked:

1. Formatting the system
2. Upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan
3. Changing the Wi-Fi router from Linksys to Dlink
4. Deleting the folder /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration and restarting the computer
5. Adding 8.8.4.4 to the DNS tab of the Advanced settings in Network Preferences
6. Gave the Macbook to the authorized Apple service center in India. They monitored the connectivity on their Wi-Fi network for 48 hours and found no issues
7. Contacted my local Wi-Fi network provider but they have no idea either. They only configure the router.

The only thing that works is this:

1. Click on the wifi bar icon(at top right corner)
2. Click on 'Turn Wi-Fi Off'
3. Click on the same wifi bar icon
4. Click on 'Turn Wi-Fi On'

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 3):

You've done a good amount of troubleshooting and at this point, you can probably assume the Mac hardware is probably fine make two conclusions:

1. your home router being different than the service router
2. your other devices re-connecting or reacting to your wifi differently

When the internet breaks on your Mac - you'll want to run the wireless diagnostics tool to determine what part of the chain is broken between the Mac and the internet.

Also - log in to the router and see if it still sees the Mac as connected (if your router can do that).

Look for the following:

1. Is the radio connected between mac and router
2. Does the Mac have a proper DHCP address from the router
3. Can the Mac ping the router
4. Can the router ping the Mac (or another device on the network ping the Mac)

If all of those are up - it's not your network and just a configuration issue on the Mac.

You'll probably need about three times of data collection and then a follow on question for someone to assist with diagnosis.